# Автоматическое нажатие кнопки b спустя время, после нажатия кнопки a

Tags: javascript, button, таймер

Есть такая вот кнопка

```
    function createTopBarButton() {
    const button = document.createElement("button")
    button.classList.add("button", "spoticon-notifications-16", "new-release-button")
    button.setAttribute("data-tooltip", BUTTON_NAME_TEXT)
    button.setAttribute("data-uri", "spotify:special:new-release")
    button.setAttribute('href','spotify:app:releases')
    return button
}
```

При нажатии она перекидывает на spotify:app:releases (далее SAR), хотя это и не единственная её задача. Стоит отметить, что она всегда закреплена в шапке, так что её можно нажать на любой странице, в том числе и на SAR.

Вторая кнопка находится на SAR, её нажатие нужно через 7 секунд, после нажатия первой кнопки. Но влезть в код SAR нет возможности. Поэтому, полагаю, задачу стоит решать при помощи той, первой кнопки. HTML код этой второй кнопки, нажатие которой нужно через 7 секунд:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она повешена на клавишу R. Так что подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, что бы спустя 7 секунд, после нажатия первой кнопки - автоматически нажималась клавиша R
*(которая в свою очередь уже активирует нажатие нужной кнопки)*

Наверное, можно попробовать и решить при помощи.

```
document.querySelector(".SyncButton").click();
```

Но при вводе в консоль это срабатывало только если она была открыта уже на spotify:app:releases, а не раньше. Так что, не уверен насчет этого варианта.

Comment: разве у кнопки есть атрибут href ?

Comment: Без понятия¯\\_(ツ)_/¯
Но вроде работает. Кликаю на неё, и перекидывает куда надо.

Но для решения вопроса можно отправной точкой использовать клик на кнопку, а уж куда там она пересылает, и пересылает ли вообще - дело десятое.

Comment: Если при нажатии на вашу кнопку идет переход на другую страницу, то никак вы таймером там кнопку не нажмете.

Comment: передавайте get на другую страницу, и если он приходит, запускайте setTimeout

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, это приложение, и первая кнопка всегда закреплена. То есть, её можно нажать всегда, на любой странице, в том числе и с той, на которую перекидывает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас есть переход между страниц (а если бы не было, то думаю такого вопроса бы не было, т.к. это легко решилось бы через setTimeout), то я вам предлагаю воспользоваться тем, что способно хранить информацию. Само лучше - использовать href, или другой параметр внутри url. Если на url вы повлиять не можете - используйте куки для этого.

Алгоритм реализации (условно)

```
var my_reclick_protect;         // Защита от повторного срабатывания.
var timer_clickcounter = 0;
var my_reclick_inner = 0;
function my_2clicktimer(){
     var x = MyGetCookie("cookie_name1");
     if (x == my_reclick_protect) return; // Если повторно - отсекаем         
     if ((x) && (x != "")) {
         //Попалось
        if (timer_clickcounter++ <7) return;
        my_reclick_protect = x; // что б повторно не сработало
        MyDeleteCookie("cookie_name1"); // Или присвоить в куки пусто
        document.querySelector(".SyncButton").click();             
        }              
     }
```

Проверочный таймер можно установить вот так `setTimer( "my_2clicktimer()",1000);` так как будут "проблемы" вроде неравномерного срабатывания, то прийдётся ставить таймер на 1 сек, и 7 тактов отсчитывать до слова "попалось" - отсекать событие 6 раз, а на 7-мой пропускать. Потому что при работе таймера если юзверь кликнет на 5-той секунде после последнего срабатывания 7-секундного таймера, то следующий тик будет через 2 секунды, и сработает раньше чем надо. Если нужно учесть "время загрузки страницы", то тогда прийдется синхронизироваться "по часам", часы можно узнать `new Date()`, тогда в куки можно записывать время клика, например.

При нажатии на кнопку 1 прийдётся в куки записать рандомное значение либо дату. Будет что-то вроде

```
 function mybutton1_click() {
    MySetCookie("cookie_name1", (new Date()));
    my_reclick_inner = 1;
    }
```

Если с "пробросом" первой кнопки всё туго (хотя click должен срабатывать раньше чем href переход) то есть варианты, а)добавить код в submit (если используется форма), а на крайний случай - добавить "проброшеную" кнопку, а оригинальную скрыть или сделать "однопиксельной" и кликать через "click()".

По поводу cookie, для них не договорились о встроеной "поддержке" браузером, нужно использовать или jQuery  `$.cookie("myCooke")` и `$.cookie("myCooke", "yjdjt pyfxtybt")` или плагин, или взять готовую функцию написаную на javascript , зависит от того какие библиотеки вы использовали (`document.cookie` хранит все куки, напрямую с ним работать можно но сложно). Если куки нельзя использовать - выход - `location.href` и модифицировать переход - записывать "переменную" в урл перехода.

Таймер вполне может сработать до перехода на новую страницу, поэтому я добавил проверку что бы до 7 раз считало, имя ввиду то что за 7 секунд уже новая страница прогрузится, если это не произошло - я добавил флаг "my_reclick_inner", который будет 1 если переход не произошёл. Тут ещё есть "граничный" случай, например что старая страница активна 8 секунд, а новая загрузится на 9-той, нужно ли это учитывать - надо подумать. Эксперементально думаю этот костяк уже можно заставить работать.

---

UDP: Как решить через setTimeout

```
    function mybutton1_click() {
             window.setTimeout('document.querySelector(".SyncButton").click();',7000);
       // Возможно добавить проброс 
       }
```

Это будет работать только если не происходит после нажатия кнопки переход на другую страницу.

Comment: *Т.к. это легко решилось бы через setTimeout*

Легко лишь в том случае, если у меня есть знания, как это решить через setTimeout. А у меня их нет. Ценю, что вы столько расписали, правда, спасибо. Но, полагаю, существует более простое решение.

Comment: Если нет перехода, то  setTimeout. Если есть переход - то проще врядли выдет.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, 
*window.setTimeout('document.querySelector(".SyncButton").click();',7000);*
Предполагается вписать в код первой кнопки, код которой я представил в самом начале вопроса?

Comment: Да. Один вид кавычек можно вкладывать в другой без экранирования. Это старая форма записи (провереная), есть так же новая, форма записи кажется так `window.setTimeout(function () {document.querySelector(".SyncButton").click(); } ,7000);` но это не точно, надо полистать примеры в сети.

Comment: А проблема возникает не из-за того, что при переходе не может найтись .SyncButton? Разве если вместо поиска, и клика кнопки сделать автоматическое нажатие клавиши R - это не решит проблему?

Comment: То есть, вообще не важно, был переход куда то, не был, просто, что бы всегда после клика на первую кнопку- спустя 7 секунд нажималась клавиша R. Будет через 7 секунд активно поля ввода - введётся туда R, будет нужная страница - произойдёт обновление, будет другая - ничего не произойдёт.

Comment: С нажатием клавиши не уверен что хорошая идея. В разных браузерах движок по разному работает, если вы хотите дать команду движку оперы - то ничего не выйдет. Если во внутрь программы - то fireEvent или вот попроще https://qna.habr.com/q/181653 или вот https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722096/simulating-a-keypress-event-from-javascript-console но лучше сразу в нужный обработчик.

Comment: В общем, задачу решил. Правда, в обход идеи с двумя кнопками. Но решением стало *window.setTimeout('document.querySelector(".SyncButton").click();',7000);*
Так что большое спасибо)